# Window loose the scroll position when overflow is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm dinamically appliyng `overflow: hidden` to `html` and `body` with `jQuery` when I click on a `div`

```
$(".mydiv").on("click", function() {
   $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

When I do this the window goes to the top of the page and loose the scroll position.
It recovers then the scroll position when I do:

```
$("html, body").css("overflow", "");
```

This happens when the user click outside the `div` I opened before

Any clue?

Comment: As far as I know, most browsers should preserve the scroll position. Does this happen in every browser? Would it be possible to post a fiddle?

Comment: How do you trigger the `$("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");` ?

Comment: @Turnip click event

Comment: Click event on what? Show us the full code.

Comment: Click event on a div that opens a custom modal. The behaviour should be the same as https://www.behance.net/ opens its works. You click on a thumbnail and it applies overflow: hidden on both html and body

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that shows the issue? A div would not behave as you describe unless there is other code that you haven't shown here. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1j55mwfh/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess and assume that you are using an `<a href="#">` to trigger the toggling of your CSS properties.

This will cause the page to jump to the top unless you actively prevent it from happening with javascript.

Example:

```js
$('.overflow-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // prevent '#' navigation
  $("body").toggleClass('overflow-hidden');
});
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflow-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="overflow-toggle">Toggle overflow</a>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
```

Here is the same example *without* preventing the scroll:

```js
$('.overflow-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  $("body").toggleClass('overflow-hidden');
});
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflow-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="overflow-toggle">Toggle overflow</a>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque euismod orci vitae elementum sagittis. Suspendisse id consectetur nibh. Nam efficitur, enim eu molestie pretium, est risus eleifend quam, at fringilla nibh massa nec elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin
  magna at orci placerat, ut fermentum tellus aliquam. Praesent a erat nec tortor pulvinar malesuada. Pellentesque mollis feugiat ligula, quis posuere enim scelerisque bibendum. Sed lacinia sem semper elit consectetur, vel porta eros ornare. Praesent
  ullamcorper euismod odio, sed bibendum odio facilisis sed. Cras elementum vitae lectus ac feugiat. Curabitur eleifend elit tortor, quis blandit eros sollicitudin quis. Vestibulum semper erat et rhoncus volutpat. Sed eget semper lectus.
</p>
<p>
  Cras at turpis consequat, condimentum dui vel, fermentum ligula. Phasellus a lorem vel leo efficitur elementum. Praesent tempus dui vel est placerat lacinia. Suspendisse semper erat sapien, a rhoncus lectus vulputate eget. Proin nec risus lectus. Curabitur
  eget iaculis dolor, nec interdum metus. Donec venenatis tortor nec turpis congue, eleifend accumsan velit aliquet.
</p>
<p>
  In sed pharetra arcu. Sed cursus et nibh quis porta. Fusce viverra placerat erat. Fusce sollicitudin tortor id mauris varius tempus. Integer fringilla nisi orci, id rhoncus tellus condimentum in. Nulla blandit imperdiet felis at venenatis. Aenean lectus
  elit, pretium quis erat id, tincidunt malesuada eros. Vestibulum nec orci faucibus, finibus nulla ac, posuere felis.
</p>
```

I don't think it is necessary to apply `overflow: hidden` to both `html` *and* `body`